# Extend Angular6 Dynamic Forms Example by Using Array of Form Parts

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, dynamic, angular-reactive-forms

I tried to extend the Angular example of Dynamic Forms, by using an Array with {names and QuestionBase[]}-objects.
*I'm having 0 problems with the standard implementation, just with my own edits.*
I think I'm not having trouble when receiving the new mockup-data, but when creating the FormGroup, especially about the property:valid of it.
Hopefully you can help me out here.
   I get the following error message:

> DynamicFormQuestionComponent.html:13 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'valid' of undefined(…)

AND the context

> DynamicFormQuestionComponent.html:13 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 11, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}

That's what I added to the question.service.ts:

```
getDummies() {
let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [

  new DropdownQuestion({
    key: 'brave2',
    label: 'Bravery Rating',
    options: [
      {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
      {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
      {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
      {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
    ],
    order: 20
  })];
let questions2: QuestionBase<any>[] = [
  new TextboxQuestion( {
    key: 'BG',
    label: 'Begründung',
    value: '',
    required: true,
    order: 3
  })
];
let object = [{name: 'test',data: questions2},
  {name: 'test2', data: questions}];

return object;
```

In my component I changed in the template(that is shown, so app.component.html or form-page for my part):

```
<app-dynamic-forms [questions]="questions" [dummies]="dummies"></app-dynamic-forms>
```

and in the .ts:

```
 dummies: any ;
```

and especially the constructor:

```
this.dummies = service.getDummies();
```

dynamic-forms.component.ts(yes I changed the name of the whole component by adding an "s"):

```
 @Input() dummies: any[] = [];
form2: FormGroup;
```

ngOnInit:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.dummies.length; i++){
  this.form2  = this.qcs.toFormGroup(this.dummies[i].data);
```

template(added this into the -tag):

```
<div *ngFor="let dummy of dummies, let i = index">
      <h3>{{dummy.name}}</h3>
      <p>{{dummy.data}}</p>
      <app-question [question]="dummy.data[i]" [form]="form2"> </app-question>
    </div>
```

I added all relevant files to this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5MMYhJikxciLA43DTIJC?p=preview).

Thanks in advance!